# Can I do this entire layout with RelativeLayout?

Tags: android

Here's a screenshot of the layout I'm looking for:

http://www.vimtips.org/media/ll.png

Can this all be done with one RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. You'll most likely be using XML attributes like android:layout_toRightOf and such. A really good reference can be found here: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html

I believe it was written by Romain Guy. Correct me if I'm wrong.